# How do you assign values when there is a weak entity?

Tags: sql

Good evening everyone! I am studying Databasetechnique and i have an assigment to make. First is to create a table called skier, then competition.

I did this:

```
CREATE TABLE skier (

SkName varchar(20),
weight int,

primary key(SkName)

) engine = INNODB;

CREATE TABLE competition (

CompName varchar(20),
Date varchar(20),

primary key(CompName)
) engine = INNODB;

In the Er model there is a many to many relationship so i did a weak relation called Participate that looks like this:

CREATE TABLE participate (

SkName varchar(20),
CompName varchar(20),

primary key(SkName, CompName),
foreign key(SkName) references skier(SkName),
foreign key(CompName) references competition(CompName)

) engine = INNOBD;
```

The question is, lets say i want to insert data that Abraham Johsson participates in a competition called ProSkeeing.. I tried inserting the data into the participate table but got an error :/

Comment: You inserted a competition in the competition table, a skier in the skier table, and *then* inserted a record in the participate table?

Comment: It says i cant insert data into a child row :(

Comment: Let's say i want to insert that Robert Angi-Lázár participates in ProSkeeing, i figured i can insert the data into the participate table where my name + Proskeeing are both primary and foreign keys, but it says i cant insert data into a child row.

Answer (score 0):

As Eric mentioned before.  Make sure that "Robert Angi-Lázár" exists in the '**skier**' table.  Next make sure 'ProSkeeing' exists in the '**competition**' table.  You can then finally add both these values in the '**participate**' table.  Not before.  The bridging entity, in our case 'participate' table, can only have data inserted into it, AFTER the tables it references have been populated.

Comment: Thank you so much, have read alot here on stackoverflow, thought i'd try posting something here myself :) Thanks for the quick answears :D